# Create a derived table from a DAX query in PowerPivot?

Tags: powerpivot, dax

Is it possible to create a derived table in PowerPivot from a DAX query? For example, the SUMMARIZE function returns a table. But, I haven't found a way to create a table based upon the value returned by this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 2013 it is possible though not as easy as the calculated tables @greggyb refers to. This article explains how:
http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/linkback-tables-in-powerpivot-for-excel-2013

Comment: Okay, I'm familiar with this workaround. Thank you for confirming it isn't directly supported.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only product that allows calculated tables is Power BI Desktop. Power Pivot for Excel 2016 will likely get this in an update at some point. I can't speak to Power Pivot for previous versions of Excel.

Comment: Okay, that confirms what I've observed, myself. Thank you.